# Show that if the congruence $x^8\equiv a\bmod 13$ is solvable, then it has either one or four solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question.** Let $a\in \Bbb Z$. Show that if the congruence
$x^8\equiv a\bmod 13$ is solvable, then it has either one or four residue classes modulo 13 as solutions.

**Attempt.** We distinguish two cases based on $a$.

- If $13$ divides $a$. Then there is one solution, namely $a\equiv 0\bmod 13$.
- If $13$ doesn't divide $a$. Then, by letting $x:=2^i\bmod 13$ and observing $a:=2^j\bmod 13$, we have $$2^{8i}\equiv 2^j\bmod 13\Rightarrow 8i\equiv j\bmod 12.$$ As $\text{gcd}(8,12)=4$, we note that this congruence will have solutions when $4\vert j$. As we are working modulo $12$, there are three such $j$ terms that satisfy such a property, namely $j\equiv 0\bmod 12$, $j\equiv 4\bmod 12$, $j\equiv 8\bmod 12$.

---

I'm pretty sure that I am mostly right in what I've done here up until the part where I end up getting three such $j$ terms. There's meant to be four as per the question but I can't see where the fourth one comes from.

Anyone that can put me out of my misery and tell me just how much of a plonker I've been then that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are correct that there are three such $j$ terms, but the question is, for a given $j$ term, how many solutions $i$ there are (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $j$ that satisfies the equation,

there are four $i$ values (and hence four $x$ values) that are solutions.

Namely, if $j\equiv0$, the solutions are $i\equiv0, 3, 6, $ and $9\bmod12$.

If $j\equiv4$, the solutions are $i\equiv2,5,8,$ and $11\bmod12$.

If $j\equiv8$, the solutions are $i\equiv1,4,7,$ and $10\bmod12$.

This is because solutions of $8i\equiv j\bmod12$ correspond to solutions of $2i\equiv\frac j4\bmod3$.

The one solution $\bmod 3$ corresponds to four solutions $\bmod 12$.

Comment: Ah of course, silly me for not fully understanding what the question is fully about. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

$2$ is a primitive root mod $13$, i.e. $2^{i} \equiv 1 \mod 13$ if and only if $i$ is divisible by $12$.  Thus $(2^i)^8 \equiv 1 \mod 13$ if and only if $i$ is divisible by $3$, and $(2^i)^8 \equiv (2^j)^8 \mod 13$ if and only if $i-j$ is divisible by $3$.  For any
$a \ne 0$ and any solution $x$ of $x^8 \equiv a \mod 13$, the other solutions are $2^3 x$, $2^6 x$, and $2^9 x$.  That makes four.

Comment: since $5^2\equiv8^2\equiv-1\bmod13$, it is easily verified that if $x^8\equiv a\bmod13$, then $(8x)^8\equiv(-x)^8\equiv(5x)^8\equiv1\bmod13 $ too